# How do I ensure a PHP variable is available in index.php after being changed in a second php file (via a jQuery load())?

Tags: php, jquery, variables

In my `index.php` I have the following jQuery code for responding to clicking an image:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click',".i-give-up", function() {
        $("#take-a-guess").load("get_snippet.php");

        [...snip...]

        generate_HSK2_circle(<?php echo $answer_data["HSK2level"]; ?>);
    });
</script>
```

When I click the image, it loads `get_snippet.php` which performs and processes a MySQL query.  Moreover, if I add

```
echo "<script>console.log('get_snippet[new] HSK2 level: " . $answer_data["HSK2level"] . "' );</script>";
```

to the end of `get_snippet.php`, I can see the correct variable for `$answer_data["HSK2level"]` in `get_snippet.php`.

The problem is that the variable `$answer_data["HSK2level"]` in `index.php` does not change as a result of loading `get_snippet.php`.

**Question**: How do I ensure a PHP variable is available in index.php after being changed in a second php file (via a jQuery load())?

Comment: Since php exists on server only and page is in browser already where only js runs, it's hard to tell if you actually want to be able to update a js  variable for the next `click` or actually need to store this new data server side for subsequent page load use. My guess is it has to do with running `generate_HSK2_circle(()` with new variable which would need to be js variable

Comment: I only want to update JavaScript variables.  Actually, all I want to do is call the function `generate_HSK2_circle(...)`, which draws a [circle](https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress) that varies with `$answer_data["HSK2level"]`.

Comment: Ok...my answer makes that assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are actually wanting to store the php value of `$answer_data["HSK2level"]` in a javascript variable so each time you call `generate_HSK2_circle()` you pass in the most current value

Note that ajax is asynchronous also so you need to use a complete callback before proceeding with new data

To do that your js would look like:

```
<script>
    // new js variable recieves value on page load from php
    var answer_data = <?php echo $answer_data["HSK2level"]; ?>;

    $(document).on('click',".i-give-up", function() {
        // use complete callback of load to assure new data loaded
        $("#take-a-guess").load("get_snippet.php", function(){
          // new data has loaded
          [...snip...]
          // use the js variable in function call
          generate_HSK2_circle(answer_data);
        });

       
    });
</script>
```

Then in your new script tag (from load) update that js variable value

```
echo "<script>answer_data=". $answer_data['HSK2level']. "</script>";
```

If this new script tag is the only data being sent from server in `load()` a more appropriate approach would be to send json and use `$.getJSON` and manually update the js variable from the response object

Answer (score 1):

The `index.php` file is not going to change after it is already rendered, unless PHP is processed on the server.

In order to pass this data, you may want to look into using a query string and redirecting back to index.php with a get variable.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get

Then in your `get_snippet.php`, you would direct to `index.php?answer=...` and retrieve it via `htmlspecialchars($_GET["answer"])`